# Using laravel 4, able to access files outside of public

Tags: security, permissions, laravel-4, public

I want to show a thumbnail image and I do so like so.

```
{{HTML::image('..\data\folders\010042.TestImage.jpg', 'pic', array('id' => 'Thumnail', 'HEIGHT'=>50, 'WIDTH'=>50))}}
```

Then I wanted to link the thumnail image to the full size image.

```
{{HTML::link('..\data\folders\010042.TestImage.jpg',HTML::image('..\data\folders\010042.TestImage.jpg', 'pic', array('id' => 'Thumnail', 'HEIGHT'=>50, 'WIDTH'=>50)))}}
```

And when I clicked on it, I seen the image.  It works.  But it shouldn't; that image isn't in public.

I was even able to access a view

```
http://localhost/myapp/app/views/hello.php
```

Is there something wrong with my installation/setup?  What should I look at/change.

I do know that to show an image that isn't in the public directory, I should have a link to my route and have some sort of view controller to pull the image out for me and place in the view like I did above.  I'd just like to know how to lock laravel down so to speak.

Thank you.

Comment: From the looks of it, that happens because you're currently on your local development machine and your root is at http://localhost/, hence you're able to access all the child directory of it. In your production server you should set the root directory to laravel's public/index.php so when people access yourwebsite.com they won't be able to access the folder above public. This is already handled by laravel's .htaccess by default.

Comment: ah, ty, I thought it was something like that, I was thinking, if I had other projects or files in my wamp folder I should be able to access them using my browser.  But I wasn't suer, thanks again for clearing that up for me.